# Continuity of a function $g(x)$ at $x=1$ where $(f(x) \cdot g(x))'$ exist at $x=1$

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

say,$$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$$ $$f(x)=(x-1)(x^2+\sin x)$$
and $g:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is an arbitrary function.
Given: $$h(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)\ \ \ \ \ \forall \in \mathbb R$$

also given $h'(1)$ exist. Comment on the continuity of $g(x)\ at\ x=1$.

My attempt: $f(1)=0$ $$h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow h'(1)=f'(1)g(1)+f(1)g'(1)$$
$$\Rightarrow h'(1)=f'(1)g(1)$$
$$\Rightarrow g(1)=\frac{h'(1)}{f'(1)}$$
hence $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$

Comment: You cannot use the product rule unless *you know* both functions are differentiable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if $g(x)$ is a function returning zero for every input except $x = 1$, where it returns $1$? Then $h(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and is clearly differentiable, but $g(x)$ is clearly not continuous at $x = 1$.

I don't quite understand your attempted proof unfortunately. First, the product rule is used to calculate the derivative of a product of two *differentiable* functions. If $f$ and $g$ aren't necessarily differentiable, then you can't apply it here. Second, even the conclusion of the proof does not necessarily show it's continuous. Instead, you want to show that as $x \to 1$, $g(x) \to g(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;g\;$ be the most non-continuous function at $\;x=1\;$ **but** bounded in some neighborhood of that point...For example, take

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x=1\\{}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\implies h(x)=f(x)g(x)=0$$

and thus $\;h(x)\;$ is infinitely differentiable everywhere, yet $\;g\;$ isn't continuous at $\;x=1\;$

Comment: Ha! We came up with same counterexample...

Comment: @paulinho Hey, I didn't see your answer until now. Well, it is pretty standard to try to use this kind of basic counter examples...

Comment: a counter example is also appreciated